# How to run multiple line of vimscript command under cursor with one keymap?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

**Overview**: 1 question + a half question of similar context (under **similar use case**)

**Goal**:
I have some vimL code in buffer, I want to run them, via press a key.

**Description**:

Similar to `gc{motion_or_text_object}` -- type `'gcip'` to comment a whole paragraph, or
`'gc3j'` to comment 4 lines. (after tComment was installed)

or `'>i}'` to indent a block, `'4<<'` to unindent 4 lines.

**current partial solution**:
currently I use visual mode and below map:

```
vnoremap <F2> :<c-u>exec join(getline("'<","'>"),"\n")<CR>
```

but sometimes is more natural to use operator-pending mode, and some other times it's
better to use line magic.

- How could I make that work for operator-pending mode and/or line-magic??

**similar use case**:

Also I have a partial solution for run external command instead of vimscript command.

```
" below nnoremap works for both single line and multiple line, 
" both 'qr' and '5qr' work.  (note the dot before w)
nnoremap qr :.w !bash -euo pipefail<CR>
vnoremap qr :w !bash -euo pipefail<CR>
```

which works for both visual selection, and line-magic; but currently I have no idea how to modify that so
that it will work for {motion_or_text_object} too.

- Any clue? to make it work for operator-pending mode??

Comment: operator-pending (with-motion): 'qr5j' to run current line and 5 line below. operator-pending (with text-object): 'qrip' to run current paragraph of code.   line-magic, 6qr to run 6 line code.    see `:h ip`, `:h operator`, `:h operator-pending`, `:h text-object` and similar ones, -- just in case some one will be in doubt.

Comment: for those who may wanna to try above keymap. **Note** I have disabled macro `map q <Nop>`, and use q as yet another leader key. also I use <Space> as my primary leader key, `let mapleader = " " `.

Answer (score 3):

You need a *custom operator* that executes the text that the `{motion}` moves over. As Vim turns this into two marks, the solution is similar to your visual-mode mapping (as long as you only want to execute whole lines). The following is based on `:help :map-operator`:

```
nnoremap <F2> :set opfunc=ExecuteLines<CR>g@
function! ExecuteLines(type)
    exec join(getline("'[","']"),"\n")
endfunction
```

With this, you can execute the lines with `<F2>{motion}`. To handle arbitrary text (not just whole lines), you'd have to evaluate the `a:type` argument, and grab the exact text, probably by defining a visual selection and yanking that into a register.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yank those lines.
2. Do `:@"`.

In a visual mode mapping:

```
xnoremap <key> y:@"<CR>
```

Usage:

```
vip<key>
```

But, frankly, it's too easy to do to warrant a mapping.

Comment: that's  definitely **not** what I ask for. Do note in my description of the problem, my current solution "visual select" then "press <F2>" is  more efficient than your currently proposed solution. what I ask is a more efficient approach than that..

Comment: What does "using operator pending mode" means to you? And "line magic"? If you want to define an operator can't you simply ask for it (after reading the appropriate help page and trying something)?

Comment: operator-pending (with-motion): 'qr5j' to run current line and 5 line below. operator-pending (with text-object): 'qrip' to run current paragraph of code.   line-magic, 6qr to run 6 line code.    see `:h operator`, `:h operator-pending` and `:h text-object`

Comment: I know what "operator-pending mode" is, thanks. But "line-magic" means nothing in Vim. What you want is an "operator"...  did you read `:help :map-operator`?

Comment: And no, your current solution is not more efficient than my proposed solution.

Answer (score -1):

You might find my vimteractive plugin gives the functionality you desire, as it allows you to send lines from a buffer to a bash terminal with the key combination Ctrl-S (as well as many other REPLs):

https://github.com/williamjameshandley/vimteractive